# When should we use genre tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should every question about a game include a tag that fits it into one or more genres? Should we only use genre tags for game-rec and family questions? Should we not have any genre tags at all?

I removed the roguelike tag from [How can I survive Gehennom?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/how-can-i-survive-gehennom) because it wasn't adding any additional meaning or context to the question; Grace Note reverted.

Comment: I thought I had read a discussion about this already, so feel free to close as exact duplicate if we have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ### This answer was an outdated policy
>
> Our current policy is that **genre tags are only used if the question is about the genre**. You can read additional detail as to this reasoning in [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/how-should-i-tag-on-gaming-se-are-genre-tags-used/3321#3321)

If you want to read the original accepted answer, check out [the revision history](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/837/revisions).

Comment: Unless a tag is completely meaningless or simply doesn't apply at all to the question, I can't see how removing it would ever add value to the question.

Comment: ie, whenever I feel like it and there's an empty tag slot.

Comment: @antony That's one way to sum it up, but don't forget to ensure that the tag is applicable! And when it comes to games that fall into multiple genres... we haven't really approached how to tag those, yet. That'd be a separate inquiry, I would imagine, because I'm not sure how we should handle those.

Comment: I like that genre tags sort of take the place of game-rec.  If you want a good [Real-Time-Strategy] merely selecting the tag will give you a good cross section of the genre.

Comment: If the consensus is that we want to start tagging questions with the genre (as long as there is room for the tag and we're sure about the genre), then I can start doing this over the next few days. Small batches would be best so we don't push new questions off the frontpage.